# Why can't I merge these remote branches?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am learning git and trying to merge my origin/dev branch into my origin/master branch because origin/dev has the latest updates:

I am typing:

```
git pull origin dev:temp
git push origin temp:master
```

But I get this message

```
To bitbucket.org:fakename/app-ios.git
 ! [rejected]        temp -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@bitbucket.org:fakename/app-ios.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
hint: counterpart. Check out this branch and integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

this is my current graph (commit codes are fake for this posting)

```
*   23f6a52 (origin/master, origin/HEAD) finalizing merge
|\  
| * gab012e (HEAD -> dev, origin/dev, temp) added .gitignore to dev branch
```

I want origin/master to have the data of origin/dev but not sure why it isn't merging?

I have everything backed up...

Thank you!

Comment: The history between your `dev` and `master` branches is different. Do you want to merge `dev` onto `master` or replace `master` with `dev`? If it's the first I'd go with: `git pull origin master:temp; git checkout temp; git merge origin/dev; git push origin temp:master`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TL;DR

You mention in a comment a problem with `xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate`.  This file should not be committed.  You'll want to delete the file and make new commits that omit it.  Whether or not you'll want to go back and replace all your *existing* commits with new-and-improved commits that *also* omit the file is up to you.  This process can be painful, but *not* doing it has its own separate pains.

(Note: I don't use Xcode and am not sure how much of a problem it is if Git *removes* the file from your working tree, although I suspect Xcode will just re-create it, i.e., not that terrible.  I base the "don't commit it" on other answers, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16535092/1256452).)

## Long

This:

> ```
> *   23f6a52 (origin/master, origin/HEAD) finalizing merge
> |\  
> | * gab012e (HEAD -> dev, origin/dev, temp) added .gitignore to dev branch
> ```

shows that there is already a merge commit—namely `23f6a52`—that combines commit `gab012e` (that one seems to be the fake hash since real hash IDs are represented as [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) numbers) with some other commit, whose hash ID we cannot see as it is off the bottom of the screen.  I am guessing, but perhaps this is the merge you want to make, already made.

Your own repository calls commit `23f6a52` by the name `origin/master`, which is your Git's memory of `origin`'s `master` branch.  Assuming this is up to date, that certainly explains the error here:

> ```
> To bitbucket.org:fakename/app-ios.git
>  ! [rejected]        temp -> master (non-fast-forward)
> ```

Your `git push` called up the Git over at bitbucket and asked them if they knew about commit `gab012e`.  They will have, so they will say *I already have that one* and the first part of `git push` is done.  The remaining part consists of a polite request: *Please, if it's OK, set your `master` to point to commit hash ID `gab012e`.*

They say: *But that's not OK.  If I do that, I'll lose my commit, `23f6a52`, off the end of my `master`.*  (They don't literally say that, they just say *no, it's not a fast-forward so it's not OK* but that's what this *means*.)

> I want `origin/master` to have the data of `origin/dev`

To do that, you might well have to *remove* this merge.

> but not sure why it isn't merging?

It's (apparently) already merged, via commit `23f6a52`.

(Note that the snapshot in `23f6a52` need not *match* the snapshot in `gab012e`, since merge does not mean "make same".  It's not possible to tell, from what you have shown here, what's in the two snapshots.  It's also not possible to tell how this relates to your own `master`, if it does.)

#### What not to do

> I am learning git and trying to merge my origin/dev branch into my origin/master branch ...
>
> ```
> git pull origin dev:temp
> ```

Running this command is probably a bad idea, especially if you're still learning Git.  This is a *very* complex combination.

Not everyone agrees with me, but I recommend that newbies *avoid* `git pull`.  What it does is run two Git commands:

- First, `git pull` runs `git fetch`.  Nearly every argument you pass to `git pull` goes straight to `git fetch`, and in this case, `git pull origin dev:temp` runs `git fetch origin dev:temp`.  This is a complex command as it uses a full refspec, `dev:temp`, that directs Git to do the creation or fast-forward of your own (local) branch `temp` based on the result of fetching `origin`'s `dev`.
- Then, assuming the `git fetch` succeeds, `git pull` goes on to run a second command.  The choice of second command is itself somewhat complicated.  If you have never configured anything else, the second command is (normally) `git merge`.  If you have configured pull to run rebase, it's normally `git rebase`.  You can override these at the time you run `git pull` (though you didn't, so it probably used `git merge`, which probably ended up being a no-op).

Each of these various steps is potentially somewhat complicated.  It's very difficult to predict the result in some cases, and the result you *observe* may be rather misleading.  If you're still a beginner, I think it is better to run the various commands separately, and observe what they do.  This puts you in a better position to understand *which second command you might want* (if any!), *what they do*, and *when to use each*.

#### What to do

Start with `git fetch origin` (or simply `git fetch`, which defaults to `origin`).<sup>1</sup>  This:

- uses the short name `origin` to find a URL;
- uses the resulting URL to call up some other Git;
- asks the other Git what branches (and other names) *they* have, and what commits go with those names;
- brings over any commits they have, that you don't, that your Git wants—usually that's "all of them";<sup>2</sup> and finally
- updates your *remote-tracking names* like `origin/master` and `origin/dev`, based on the commits that *their* names identify.

(A limited fetch, like `git fetch origin dev`, only updates `origin/dev`, since it doesn't bother to get any new commits from their `master`.)

Now that you have the commits that *they* have, see if you have any commits that they *don't* have, that you want them to have right now.  For instance, if your `dev` is strictly ahead of their `dev`—say, you have two new commits that they don't, and they have no commits that you don't—and you'd like them to save these two commits in case your laptop bursts into flames while you take a quick break,<sup>3</sup> you can use `git push` to send these commits.  See the notes on `git push` below.  If you're willing to wait, or your Git is both ahead *and behind* their Git, see the notes on merging below.

(You already know how to see which commits who has, with `git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph` or similar.)

**The really nice thing about `git fetch` is that you can do it any time.**  All it does is obtain any *new* commits from the other Git, and then update your own remote-tracking (`origin/*`) names.  It does not affect anything you are doing—well, as long as you don't use the `dev:temp` style syntax, anyway.

---

<sup>1</sup>The actual default is the remote for the *current branch*, if it has one.  If not, the default is the literal string `origin`.  If you have only the one remote, named `origin`, `origin` is going to be the right one, and in simpler setups you will only have the one remote.

<sup>2</sup>The exceptions here are *single-branch* clones and some other special cases.  Also, if you use `git fetch remote somebranch`, for instance, your Git will only bother bringing over the new commits it needs to update `remote/somebranch`.  That means a later `git fetch` will need to bring over any commits this `git fetch` skipped.  If you have a slow Internet connection, sometimes this is worthwhile, but usually it's best to bring over everything at once since it tends to compress better that way: if `git fetch xyz br1` takes 10 minutes and `git fetch xyz br2` also takes 10 minutes, `git fetch xyz` probably *doesn't* take 20 minutes, but rather more like 12 to 15 minutes.  These numbers are made up on the spot (like 37.12% of all statistics) but the general idea is right: if you pay less, in installments, over time, you wind up paying more than if you just pay the whole thing up front.

<sup>3</sup>See, e.g., https://abcnews.go.com/WNT/video/charging-laptop-bursts-flames-moment-caught-home-camera-45312573

---

#### If you're strictly behind, consider a fast-forward merge

As you've probably already gathered:

- Each Git commit has a hash ID.  This hash ID uniquely identifies that one particular commit.  This ID is unique across *every* Git repository, and Git guarantees that every Git will agree that *that* commit gets *that* ID, by computing the hash ID as a cryptographic checksum of the commit's content.
- Each Git commit has a full snapshot of all of the files that Git knows about.
- Each commit also has some *metadata*, i.e., information about the commit.  This includes the name and email address of the person who made the commit (the "author"), and a date-and-time-stamp.  It includes other information, such as the log message.  And—crucially for Git—it includes a list of *previous* or *parent* commits.  The parent links are what form the commit graph you see in the `git log --graph` output.

If your own `dev` is behind `origin/dev` and not *ahead of* `origin/dev` as well—so that there is no divergence—that means someone sent new commits to the `dev` over on `origin`.  If you'd like those commits to appear in your own `dev`, now is the time to do:

```
git checkout dev
git merge origin/dev
```

or the simpler:

```
git checkout dev && git merge
```

This second version assumes that `origin/dev` is set as the *upstream* of `dev`: the `git merge` command will default to using the upstream, if you don't specify something here.  I actually like to add the `--ff-only` flag here, because I only want the merge to succeed if it *can* be done as a fast-forward.  (I have an alias, `git mff`, that runs `git merge --ff-only`, and that's what I use.)  This allows me to be a little bit careless / cavalier, and just run the command without first checking whether it *would* do a fast-forward.

#### If you're both ahead *and* behind, you will generally want to merge or rebase

If you have new commits that they don't, *and* they have new commits that you don't, you probably need to combine your work with their work.  This is where the second command that `git pull` runs comes in:

- `git merge` will do a full three-way merge (not just a fast-forward).
- `git rebase` will take your existing commits and copy them to new-and-supposedly-improved commits.  If the copying all works, rebase will then abandon the old (and lousy?) commits for the new (and improved?) ones.

Rebasing is much more complicated than merging, because it works on a commit-by-commit basis.  It uses `git cherry-pick`, or something reasonably close to equivalent,<sup>4</sup> for *each* commit that needs to be copied.<sup>5</sup>  Each of these cherry-pick operations can stop in the middle with a merge conflict, so if `git rebase` needs to copy 5 commits, that's 5 chances to stop.  A merge only has one chance to stop in the middle with a merge conflict.  (On the other hand, the one conflict could be large, vs 5 smaller ones.)

The choice of whether to merge or rebase here is yours.  One of the things I think is broken about `git pull`, though, is that you must *make* this choice *before* you see whether a merge would be a fast-forward or a real merge.  Recently, Git has grown the option to make `git pull` only do a merge *if* it's a fast-forward merge.  I claim that this is the right default (but it's not the current default, so I still recommend avoiding `git pull`).

---

<sup>4</sup>Modern Git uses cherry-pick but has it built in to rebase.  Older versions of Git use cherry-pick sometimes, and `git am` sometimes, and rebase is a shell script.  You can make those versions of Git use rebase by adding `-m` and/or `-s` arguments, or doing an interactive rebase; interactive rebase literally runs `git cherry-pick`.

<sup>5</sup>The set of commits that is copied is ... complicated, especially in modern Git with the `--fork-point` option.  In the normal simple cases, however, that's every commit that you have, that they don't.

---

#### Full-blown merging

To do a full-blown three-way merge, I recommend that you use a (local) branch, such as `dev` or `master` (or `main` if you switch from `master` to `main`):

- Run `git checkout` or `git switch` (in Git 2.23 or later) with the branch name you want to use for the new merge commit.  This puts you "on" that branch, in that `git status` will now say `on branch dev` or whatever.
- Run `git merge name` or `git merge commit-hash-ID` to start the merge process.  Using a name here, as in `git checkout master && git merge dev`, sets up the default commit message to use the branch name (e.g., `merge branch dev`).  Other than that, a hash ID is just as good as a name.  Hash IDs are hard to type in, so you probably want to use the name.  You should just realize that Git doesn't *need* a name here.  It *needs* a hash ID, and it just turns the name *into* a hash ID to do the actual merging.

The merge itself works by finding a *shared* commit.  Suppose we have a commit graph like this:

```
          I--J   <-- master (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- dev
```

which indicates that there are two commits on `master` that are not on `dev`, and vice versa.  The best commit that's on *both* branches, in this case, is commit `H`.  (Remember, later commits are towards the right, earlier commits are towards the left, and Git starts from the two end-point commits and works backwards.  So commit `H` is the first *shared* commit, on both branches, and is thus the *best* shared commit.)

The merge process now works by comparing the snapshot in commit `H` to each of the two snapshots in the two selected commits:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-H> <hash-of-J>   # what "we" did on master
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-H> <hash-of-L>   # what "they" did on dev
```

Merge works by combining these two sets of changes, applying the combined changes to the snapshot in commit `H`—this keeps "our" changes while adding "theirs"—and making a new commit from the result.  Or, if the combining goes wrong, merge stops in the middle, leaving a mess in your working tree and Git's index, and your job becomes fixing up the mess and continuing the merge.

Assuming all goes well, Git makes a new *merge commit*, which is a commit with two parents.<sup>6</sup>  We can draw that in like this:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M   <-- master (HEAD)
         \    /
          K--L   <-- dev
```

Note that if commit `J` was the tip of `origin/master` (and still is), you can now `git push origin master` to send commit `M` to `origin`.  This commit will be strictly ahead of their own `master`—a *fast forward* as far as they are concerned—so they are likely to accept this push.

---

<sup>6</sup>Technically, a merge commit is any commit with two *or more* parents, but there's nothing you can do with more than two that you couldn't do with extra merges.  In fact, it's kind of the other way around: there are things you *can't* do with a so-called octopus merge, with 3 or more parents, that you *could* do with multiple two-parent merges.  That's kind of their primary value: if you encounter one, you could expect it to be one of these simpler merges.  A true Git Jedi Master (or Sith Lord) could make one that violates these expectations, though.

---

#### `git push`

Once you have a local branch that, as compared with the same branch name over on `origin` (or some other remote Git), you can run `git push` to send the new commits to their Git.  As with `git fetch`, this starts by calling up their Git—but this time you're the sender, not the receiver, and your Git lists out the hash ID of some commit of your choice.

In the example above, where we just made new commit `M`, so that that is the only commit we have that they don't, when we run `git push origin master`—note that we should use *all four words* here, and not leave out either `origin` or `master`<sup>7</sup>—our Git will offer their Git new commit `M`, which they'll take, then offer both parents of `M`, which they'll decline with *no thanks, I already have that*.  We'll then package up commit `M`, including its files, and send the package over.  Then our Git will ask their Git, politely, to *please, if it's OK, set your `master` to _____*, filling in the blank with the hash ID of commit `M`.

**They will now check that this operation is, for them, a fast-forward.**  If it is, they will accept the request,<sup>8</sup> and now their `master` will have commit `M`.  Ours will as well, because we put it on our `master` when we made it.

---

<sup>7</sup>If you run `git push` with no arguments, Git fills in the `origin` part the same way it does for `git fetch` with no arguments.  It then fills in the *branch name* part based on `push.default`.  The `push.default` setting in Git version 2 (all version 2 versions) is `simple`, which means *use the current branch*.  However, the default setting in Git version 1 is `matching`.  This is sometimes what you want, but rarely so for newbies, which is why they changed it in Git 2.x.

I actually tend to use `git push origin HEAD`, myself.  `HEAD` translates to *the current branch*.  In the special case of making pull requests on GitHub, I sometimes use `git push origin HEAD:new branch name I make up on the spot`.  Then I rename the local branch, having figured out while typing in the `git push` command, what name I *wanted* to use for the local branch, but didn't earlier. :-)

<sup>8</sup>Depending on the site, the repository owner can often add various rules to protect particular branch names so that only whitelisted users can push directly to them.  In this case, you may need to whitelist yourself.

---

#### Removing and ignoring files that should never have been committed

It's important to remember that in Git, a *commit* is a snapshot of *all files that Git knows about* at the time you (or whoever) make that snapshot.  Once made, that snapshot cannot be changed.  In fact, nothing about any existing commit can ever be changed.  This is due to the hashing scheme Git uses.

Since each commit is stored in a form that is not usable by the rest of the computer, though, each commit has to be *extracted* into ordinary everyday files.  When Git does this, it takes the *committed* files, expands them into usable form, and sticks them into a work area.  Git calls this work area your *working tree*.

Since your working tree is an ordinary directory full of files (or set of "files and folders" if you prefer these terms), you can now make *new* files here.  Git won't know about them.  Git's list of files that it knows about is kept in what Git calls its *index*.

The index does not just *list* the files, though.  It actually holds *snapshots* of them, in pre-Git-ified form: compressed and de-duplicated, ready to go into the *next* commit.  When you use `git add`, you are telling Git: *copy this file into your index.*  If there was one in there before, it gets kicked out (i.e., not *overwritten* since these are in the archive form) and the new file goes in instead.  If the file *wasn't* in Git's index before, well, now it is, along with its name.

When you run `git commit`, Git saves *exactly those files that are in its index*, in the form they have *right then* **in** the index.  That becomes the new snapshot.  So Git's index is always your proposed *next* snapshot.<sup>9</sup>  If you avoid adding a file *to* Git's index, it doesn't go into a commit.

It's annoying and painful to manually add each file every time you change one.  So there's an en-masse *add everything* operation (in fact, multiple such operations).  But if you do that, this adds files you might want never to commit.

To prevent *that*, Git has `.gitignore`.  This file is rather misnamed.  It *will not ignore* a file that's already in Git's index.  The main thing it does is suppress *complaints* from `git status`, about untracked files Git is reminding you to add.  The file should perhaps be named `.git-do-not-complain-about-these-untracked-files`.  It also, however, stops those en-masse *add a bunch of files* operations from adding those untracked files.  So a better name is `.git-do-not-complain-about-these-untracked-files-and-do-not-auto-add-them-during-an-en-masse-add-operation`.  That's still not entirely accurate, but is a lot closer than `.gitignore`.  But it's also ridiculous, so `.gitignore` it is.

The key takeaway here is that **listing a file in `.gitignore` does not cause it to be ignored**.  It's the *absence of the file in commits* that makes it ignored.  When the file isn't in Git's index, it won't be in your *next* commit.  But if it is in some *existing* commit, and you check out that commit, Git will copy the committed file *to* its index, and then copy that file (and expand it out to useful form) to your working tree.

To take a file that is already in Git's index *out* of Git's index, we use `git rm`:

```
git rm file-that-should-not-have-been-committed
```

This removes *both* the index copy *and* the working tree copy.  To avoid removing the working tree copy *right now*, we can use:

```
git rm --cached file-that-should-not-have-been-committed
```

which removes only the *index* copy, leaving the working tree copy alone.  Then we can make a new commit, and the new commit will lack the file.

But: no *existing* commit can be changed.  So the *old* commit will *have* the file.  The difference between the old commit and the new commit will say *remove the file*.  Any use of the old commit gets you the old copy of the file.  Any switch *from* the old commit, *to* a newer commit that *lacks* the file, *removes the file*.

This is why removing a file that should never have been committed in the first place can be painful.

It's possible to take all the commits in some repository and copy *all* of them to new-and-improved commits that lack some file(s), but the result is a new *repository* that requires throwing out all copies of the old repository.  You *can* do this, especially near the start of some project, if you know everyone who has the old commits and can convince them all to switch over.

---

<sup>9</sup>There is an exception in the middle of a conflicted merge.  Here, Git's index is expanded, and you literally *can't* make a snapshot from it until you shrink it back down to its normal form, by resolving the conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

```
git checkout temp
git pull -r origin master
git push temp
```

should do the trick.

Comment: something is not working. Xcode's xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate is messing everything up